# How to dynamically change the stylesheet of an HTML page within an iFrame of another page?

Tags: jquery, css, inheritance, iframe, stylesheet

I have a web page that makes use of the jQuery UI themes. Within this page, there's an iFrame holding another HTML document that also makes use of the jQuery UI themes. Now, I have made my own theme selecter, and I'd like to know the easiest way to have it affect the page within the iFrame. For example, whenever the user selects a new theme, I simple do something like:

```
<link id="uiTheme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ui/smoothness.css" />
$("#uiTheme").attr("href", "ui/" + newTheme + ".css");
```

Where `newTheme` is the string literal of a different them (all done through a select box, and I know it all works and such). Now, how can I change the sheet being used within the frame to match that of the main page? I guess my question is how can I use the jQuery selector to grab the link with an id of `innerTheme` to change it's href attribute to the same stylesheet? Furthermore, do I even need to worry about this, or will the ui-theme of the outer page automatically descend into the frame without the frame's page itself linking to a stylesheet?

If my question is a bit confusing, I apologize. I can try to clear anything up if need be.

Comment: Are they both on the same domain?

Comment: Yes, they are both on the same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to get a reference to their link element - just add your own and it will override.

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.href = "http://full.domain.com/ui/smoothness.css";
link.type = 'text/css';
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
$('head', frameName )[0].appendChild(link);
```

However, you won't be able to modify anything in the other frame if it's coming from another domain. So if it's being served from the same domain - it may be easier to just make the change on the original page. If it's coming from another site - sadly you're out of luck.

Comment: That last line of code is what I think I was looking for. I wasn't aware that the second parameter of the selector was the "name" of the iframe, and not it's ID or something. I think something like `$("#innerTheme", "myFrame").attr("href", "ui/" + newTheme + ".css");` where `<iframe id="myFrameID" name="myFrame"></iframe>` would work, right?

Comment: The second parameter is the context that the selector should match against. By default when you give a frame an id a top-level object with the same name is created. You could also use $('head', $('#myFrameID')).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code which i hope can help a little:
It loops through the iframe stylesheets toggling them on/off

```
javascript: var i=0;
for(var j=0;j < window.frames.length;j++){
  cs=!window.frames[j].document.styleSheets[0].disabled;
  for(i=0;i<window.frames[j].document.styleSheets.length;i++) 
    window.frames[j].document.styleSheets[i].disabled=cs;
};
void(cs=true);
```

The code is based on the Bookmarklet to toggle CSS on/off [here](http://tantek.com/favelets/)

Comment: This would kinda work, though it seems to be simply toggling style sheets rather than selecting from a list of say 30 different jQuery UI themes.